# Cassandra Basic CRUD with Java / Scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax

Going to implement DAO with cassandra and java driver

Want to clarify 2 approaches

1. use CRUD for the mapping operations - https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver/java-driver/reference/crudOperations.html
2. prepare simple tables and connect entities by id`s

Which approach more appropriate ? any recommendation ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches will use prepared statements anyway.

The only difference is that when you're using the object mapper, there are some Java introspection at runtime to extract the values from Java beans. It may add some extra cost but it should not be huge unless you're inserting thousands records per second

Otherwise, you can use Achilles (www.achilles.io) which generate mapper code at runtime so there is no runtime introspection